# Using JQuery to toggle a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to JQuery and I am having some trouble getting my code to work just right. For some reason my JQuery is hiding the link (a) element. I need the link to toggle the 'wrap' div. What could I be doing wrong?

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.wrap').hide();
   $('.open').toggle(
      function() {
     ('.wrap').show();
  },
  function() {
     ('.wrap').hide();
      }
   ); // end toggle
}); // end ready
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbXYp/)

Answer (score 8):

http://jsfiddle.net/AbXYp/4/

```
$('.wrap').hide();
$('.open').click(function() {
    $('.wrap').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

So on every "Notifications" link click you're toggling the `.wrap`

The real roots of the issue with your code: The `.toggle()` event handler was **REMOVED** in jquery 1.9 -- http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/, so what you're using in your code sample is animation method http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @user2096890: 1. you've missed `$` in the hadlers 2. With toggle you cannot prevent anchor default behaviour (going to the link)

Comment: Thank you the book I am learning from is a little out dated I supposed.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your jquery with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.wrap').hide();
    $('.open').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();$('.wrap').toggle();return false;}); // end toggle
}); // end ready
```

It should work

Comment: The only thing wrong with your code is that you are not toggling the wrap and trying to toggle open which should be given click event